# How to disable "Automatically search for drivers and install" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, search

I connected my TI-89 to my Windows 7 system, and apparently it is not plug-and-play.

There was a link to a Windows configuration setting made available that gave the option to **automatically search** their windows site for drivers and **automatically install** them each time i connect an unrecognized device.

Well, I selected that link with the intention of it being temporary and just that one time. That didnt work and the location/install of a driver was not successful.

**How can I reset that setting to not automatically install** whatever drivers it thinks might be fitting? I cannot find that configuration setting when I looked for it recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesHardware.exe
```

Click on the second button, in the new Window choose the second option...

[image]

Comment: Alternate way to open the dialog: In the Start Menu search box type **change device** and click on the **Change device installation settings** option.